# Jest fails to load moment

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a very simple React component that utilizes the moment library:

```
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';

let { Component } = React;

export class SimpleApp extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        var currentDate = this.props.data[this.props.current].date;

        this.state = {
            currentDate: currentDate,
            currentFromatted: moment(currentDate).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY')
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="simple">{this.state.currentDate}</div>
        );
    }
} 

module.exports = SimpleApp;
```

And I have this test to test this component:

```
import React from 'react/addons';
import SimpleApp from '../js/components/pages/Simple.react';

var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;


jest.dontMock('../js/components/pages/Simple.react');
jest.dontMock('moment');

describe('SimpleApp', () => {
    it('should not do anything', () => {
        var data = {
            "date": "2015-07-01",
            "total": 2,
            "results":[
                {
                    "startTime": "2015-07-01T00:00:00.000",
                    "endTime": "2015-07-01T00:59:59.999",
                    "total": 2,
                    "results":[
                        {
                            "type":"motion",
                            "count":2
                        },
                        {
                            "type":"transaction",
                            "count":0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        };

        var simple = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
            <SimpleApp data={[data]} current="0" />
        );

        var div = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(simple, 'div');
        expect(div.getDOMNode().textContent).toEqual('2015-07-01');
    })
})
```

when run `npm test` I get error says cannot call method 'format' of undefined:

```
● SimpleApp › it should not do anything
  - TypeError: Cannot call method 'format' of undefined
        at new SimpleApp (/Users/xiaofanyang/workspace/solink/histogram/flux2/js/components/pages/Simple.react.js:13:69)
```

it seems that the moment library was mocked, however, I did specify not to mock it... but obviously no help...

Answer (score 0):

The way that I managed to get around this is by doing

```
jest.autoMockOff();
```

and then manually mocking anything else that I needed in the project.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

jest.dontMock 'webpack/buildin/module'
and I had to put moment in unmockedModulePathPatterns in my package.json - it wasn't enough to just unmock it in the test.

It looks like that webpack/buildin/module is a web pack loader which is included so that moment can load some other module. So it is a dependency of moment and has to be specifically not mocked. However; - I don't fully understand what it does. (Though this seems to be part of the answer: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/333)